# Ajax in HTML to update status of user as online/offline

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a MySQL database that contains a list of users and their states:

```
user01 Online
user02 Offline
user03 Online
```

and I am using PHP file to get the states:

```
<?php

//Database details
$servername = "servername";
$username = "uid";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "myDB";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql_GetURL = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT UserName, UserState FROM Users");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_GetURL)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['UserName'] . " " . $row['UserState'] . "</td></tr> <br>"; 
    }

?>
```

Now I want to use AJAX in HTML to call my php file to keep checking the state of all 3 users and if they are online, I want to call a function. How expensive is it to keep calling the php function and what would be the implementation?

So far I know that I can use AJAX to make calls every 1 second

```
$('document').ready(function () {
 setInterval(function () {getRealData()}, 1000);

 }); 

function getRealData() {
$.ajax({
         url: "user.php",
         type: "GET",
  }
}
```

Comment: Two better options than long-polling would be `websockets` or `server sent events`. Of the two it is far easier to implement SSE with a simple PHP script and a single connection from the client. Data is sent *when* the server is programmed to do so and the browser can respond when it receives the response message. The PHP script works in an infinite loop so as to prevent the client from constantly reconnecting

Comment: I am anyway using another php script to UPDATE the state of the user. So it would be better I call Ajax from that php or ?

Comment: I'd think that the update and the polling operations should be kept separate completely  - the update done by AJAX, the polling by SSE or websocket

Comment: `"...and if they are online, I want to call a function"` - online and *simply connected* to your site, online and *logged into* your site or simply online ? Is the *function* a PHP or Javascript function?